# Get specific value of row from list that has a shared edge

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I created a list that looks like this:

```
public class TriangleRegistryList
{
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public int ShapeNum { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<(float x, float y)> GetPoints()
    {
        yield return (x1, y1);
        yield return (x2, y2);
        yield return (x3, y3);
    }

    public bool IsAdjacentTo(TriangleRegistryList other)
    {
        return GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).Count() >= 2;
    }
}
```

Now I also created this class:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
        GetKCombs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
    {
        if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
        return GetKCombs(list, length - 1)
            .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => !o.Equals(t.Last())),
                (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
    }
}
```

This will check if my triangles have shared edges with each other. To do that, I have to call this line:

```
var sharedEdges = 
    triangles.GetKCombs(2)
        .Where(t => 
            t.First().IsAdjacentTo(t.Skip(1).Take(1).Single()) 
            && t.First().ShapeNum == 1
        );
```

Now I want to know how I can get the ShapeNum of the triangle that the triangle is connected to. So for example if I have a triangle with ShapeNum and I see that it has a shared edge with another triangle, I want to know what the ShapeNum of that triangle is.

**Details:**
When I have a few triangles in the list and I will check the next triangle, I want to know which **connected** triangle has the lowest ShapeNum. So for example this picture:
[image]

Then I want a result that returns me 1, because that is the lowest connected triangle to the green one. The next step would be to get the other number, so in my example is it 2. Then set every Triangle with ShapeNum=2 to 1. So the picture will look like this:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have now created this function:

```
public static bool ValidLayout()
{
    bool TriangleFound = false;
    bool IsValid;
    int SelectedTriangles = TriangleRegistry.Count(tr => tr.Value.Selected.Equals(true));
    int LowestShapeNum = 0;
    triangles = new List<TriangleRegistryList>();
    /*
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TriangleRegistryObject> row in TriangleRegistry.Where(n => n.Value.Selected == true).ToList())
    {
        triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
        {
            x1 = row.Value.x1,
            y1 = row.Value.y1,
            x2 = row.Value.x2,
            y2 = row.Value.y2,
            x3 = row.Value.x3,
            y3 = row.Value.y3,
            ShapeNum = 0
        });
    }
    */

    triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
    {
        x1 = (float)405,
        y1 = (float)701.4806,
        x2 = (float)675,
        y2 = (float)701.4806,
        x3 = (float)540,
        y3 = (float)935.3074
    });

    triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
    {
        x1 = (float)135,
        y1 = (float)701.4806,
        x2 = (float)405,
        y2 = (float)701.4806,
        x3 = (float)270,
        y3 = (float)935.3074
    });

    triangles.Add(new TriangleRegistryList
    {
        x1 = (float)270,
        y1 = (float)935.3074,
        x2 = (float)540,
        y2 = (float)935.3074,
        x3 = (float)405,
        y3 = (float)701.4806
    });

    int maxShapeNum = triangles.Max(x => x.ShapeNum);
    foreach (TriangleRegistryList triangle in triangles)
    {
        if(maxShapeNum > 0)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while(i <= maxShapeNum)
            {
                //Check if the current triangle with (ShapeNumber = i) is connected to another triangle from the list
                var sharedEdges = triangles.GetKCombs(2).Where(t => t.First().IsAdjacentTo(t.Skip(1).Take(1).Single()) && t.Skip(1).Single().ShapeNum == i);
                int sharedEdgesCount = sharedEdges.Count();
                if (sharedEdgesCount > 0)
                {
                    List<int> ConnectedShapeNumList = triangle.AdjacentShapeNumbers;

                    if (ConnectedShapeNumList != null)
                    {

                        List<int> RemovedDoublesList = ConnectedShapeNumList.Distinct().ToList();
                        RemovedDoublesList.Sort();

                        int ListLength = (from x in RemovedDoublesList select x).Distinct().Count();

                        if(ListLength != 0)
                        {
                            LowestShapeNum = RemovedDoublesList.First();
                            int HighestShapeNum = RemovedDoublesList.Last();

                            if (sharedEdgesCount > 1)
                            {
                                if (LowestShapeNum != HighestShapeNum)
                                {
                                    foreach (int x in RemovedDoublesList)
                                    {
                                        if (x != LowestShapeNum)
                                        {
                                            foreach (TriangleRegistryList OldTriangleShapeNum in triangles)
                                            {
                                                if (OldTriangleShapeNum.ShapeNum == x)
                                                {
                                                    OldTriangleShapeNum.ShapeNum = LowestShapeNum;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    triangle.ShapeNum = RemovedDoublesList.First();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                triangle.ShapeNum = RemovedDoublesList.First();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            triangle.ShapeNum = maxShapeNum + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    triangle.ShapeNum = maxShapeNum + 1;
                }

                TriangleFound = true;
                i += 1;
            }        
        }
        if(TriangleFound == false)
        {
            triangle.ShapeNum = maxShapeNum + 1;
        } 

        maxShapeNum = triangles.Max(x => x.ShapeNum);
    }

    if (maxShapeNum == 1)
    {
        IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsValid = false;
    }

    return IsValid;
}
```

Sometimes the code does work, but sometimes when all the triangles are connected it still says that there are multiple shapes detected. I have manually added the triangle coordinates in the code above, so you can try it yourself. Here are the triangle coordinates for the formation that doesn't work (which actually should have worked):

```
TriangleRegistryList Triangle_1 = new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1=405, y1=701.4806, x2=675, y2=701.4806, x3=540, y3=935.3074
};

TriangleRegistryList Triangle_2 = new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1=135, y1=701.4806, x2=405, y2=701.4806, x3=270, y3=935.3074
};

TriangleRegistryList Triangle_3 = new TriangleRegistryList
{
    x1=270, y1=935.3074, x2=540, y2=935.3074, x3=405, y3=701.4806
};
```

Comment: could you post some examplary triangles so we can play with it? it would make our life easier

Comment: I have added some details about my question and result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by adding integer property: "AdjacentShapeNum" into "TriangleRegistryList" and set it in "IsAdjacentTo" method if it finds a shared edge with another triangle.

```
public int AdjacentShapeNum { get; set; }
public bool IsAdjacentTo(TriangleRegistryList other)
{
   var isAdjacentTo = 
            GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).ToList().Count() >= 2;
            if(isAdjacentTo){
                this.AdjacentShapeNum = other.ShapeNum;
            }
            return isAdjacentTo;
}
```

Code to get "ShapeNum" of multiple triangles adjacent to the current triangle:

```
        public TriangleRegistryList()
        {
            this.AdjacentShapeNumbers = new List<int>();
        }
        public List<int> AdjacentShapeNumbers {get;set;}

        public bool IsAdjacentTo(TriangleRegistryList other)
        {
            var isAdjacentTo =  
            GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).ToList().Count() >= 2;
            if(isAdjacentTo){
                this.AdjacentShapeNumbers.Add(other.ShapeNum);
            }
            return isAdjacentTo;
        }
```

Comment: Would be nice if you will also add some text, explaining your answer

Comment: I have added some details to my question

Comment: But what if there are multiple triangles connected to 1 triangle?

Comment: Can you change the property to `List<int> AdjacentShapeNumbers => new List<int>();` and add to that list? `if(isAdjacentTo){this.AdjacentShapeNumbers.Add(other.ShapeNum); }`

Comment: The list stays empty when I call the method?

Comment: I think it should work if you initialise the list in constructor. Please check the code added above.